# Submit form as "multipart/form-data" but content-type is “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” on the server

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, multipartform-data

I'm trying to submit a form that includes a file, I'm using enctype="multipart/form-data" but the request content-type is sent as “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”, this is the part of the code:

```
<div id="uploadTest" data-role="page" align="right">
        <form id="uploadTestForm" action="/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="text" autofocus required>
                <input id="ImageFile" type="file" data-clear-btn="false" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
            <button type="submit" data-theme="a">Upload</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

This is a part of my HTML5 application that need to upload the file.
There is no JS code that run on submitting the form.

May you please help me find why I cannot submit the form as "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: Will you post a non-working fiddle? I just created one with just the markup you provided and it is properly using multipart/form-data. http://jsfiddle.net/v2Vjf/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I do not understand what you are asking, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: You can use a site like JSfiddle.net to post an example of the code. As you can see, I made an example with the html you provided and it is submitting as multipart/form-data... hence why I asked for a non-working example.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what was the problem.

I just added data-ajax="false" to the form and now it is working.